# How would I send this string one character at a time?

Tags: c

Here is the code that I have. I am unable to test it right now, so I'm just wondering if someone can verify that this will take the full `str` string and send each character individually to `TXREG`

```
char str [10];
int n;
n = sprintf(str, "%u%% %u\n", Duty_Cycle, DAC_Output);
transmit_uart(str);                    // Send the value
```

And here is the `transmit_uart()` method.

```
void transmit_uart(const char *value) {
    for(int i = 0; value[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        while(TXIF == 0) {}
        TXREG = value[i];
    }
}
```

So this should send something like

`50% 128`

Every time I call `transmit_uart()` with a string formatted the way I have it up there.

**UPDATE: I was able to test it yesterday, and this did in fact work! Thanks for all the help!**

Comment: If you want to send a character, shouldnt the function take a `char` as parameter?

Comment: Well I'm new to C. I thought that's what I had. It's supposed to take a `char` array and iterate through it sending each byte individually. I hope I've explained this clearly.

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++? We can't tell from your code and you used both tags.

Comment: C. Sorry, I'll remove the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't personally loaded it onto an MCU and tested it, yes, that looks fine as long as `TXIF` does what it looks like.

You really should use `snprintf` or a larger buffer. This is one case where overflowing the integer (as in simply having too large a value, or any negative value) would cascade into buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks! I know that the PWM value will never exceed 100%, and the DAC Output will never exceed 255, so altogether, that should be 9 characters including the space and newline characters. I set it to 10 just to be safe. Would you still suggest increasing it to say, 20?

Comment: Oh and yeah, it's supposed to loop there until `TXIF` goes high.

Comment: @WillemEllis It's best to use `snprintf` every time. But going the other route, the only safe thing is to allocate 10 digits for each `unsigned int` (assuming they are 32-bit) giving a total buffer size of 23 bytes.

Comment: @WillemEllis TXIF also has to be specified to go low as soon as the buffer is written. But details, details.

Comment: I will take your advice and use `snprintf`. Does it take the same parameters as `sprintf`? Also, I believe the UART sets it low or something. For that part I'm just converting a macro my professor provided in assembly into C haha.

Comment: @WillemEllis Typically the MCU vendor provides the macros. Check their website. `snprintf` takes an extra buffer size argument, which is what makes it safer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send string of 5-9 characters:

```
1 or 2 or 3 symbols - Duty_Cycle value,
1 symbol - % symbol,
1 symbol - space,
1 or 2 or 3 symbols - DAC_Output value,
1 symbol - \n symbol,
```

you are doing right.